# calling externally componentDidMount() in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I have a requirement in which once page gets loaded my `dropdownlist` should be populated. for that I put that code in `componentDidMount()`.

```
  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get(`http://localhost:8080/country_code`).then((res) => {
      const countryData = res.data;
      this.setState({ countryData });
      alert(countryData);
    });
  }
```

I have one user input field in which person enter the value and save it into database. I want once user save that value into DB, my dropdown should get refresh and that value should be visible in the dropdown. How can I externally call `componentDidMount()`? is there any better way to handle the same?

As of now list is getting refreshed only when user resfresh the page.

Comment: `so how can I externally call componentDidMount()?` Didn't get this. `componentDidMount` lifecycle method is used only for initial render. You should write a function to handle data once user saves it and update the state from there.

Comment: Can't really understand, after writing to DB when you get back the response, can't you just update the state like this.setState(prevState => return {...preState, countryData: [...prevState, yourresponsevariable]})

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't call externally `componentDidMount()` method !. so you need set
common function which is call in `componentDidMount()` and onChange dropdown value. see below code !

```
class App extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.handleCallApi();
  }

  handleCallApi = () => {
    axios.get(`http://localhost:8080/country_code`).then((res) => {
      const countryData = res.data;
      this.setState({ countryData });
      alert(countryData);
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.handleCallApi}>Call Api</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

Comment: it still require page refresh to update the list in UI.

Comment: Can you show the code ?? what you tried !

Comment: it worked. Mayur one help. could you pls upvote this question. somebdy did mass downvoting and they blocked my account.

Answer (score 1):

You can't call `componentDidMount` externally but you can extract the code in `componentDidMount` to a method and can call it in both `componentDidMount` and `onSave`.

```
 alertDropDown = () => {
    axios.get(`http://localhost:8080/country_code`).then((res) => {
          const countryData = res.data;
          this.setState({ countryData });
          alert(countryData);
        });
    }
```

**componentDidMount**

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.alertDropDown()
}
```

**On DB save method**

```
onSave = () => {
 this.alertDropDown()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't call the **componentDidMount()**, as it's a lifecycle method and is called at initial render. You can expose a function and call that function from inside the **componentDidMount()** something like:

```
updateDropdownData = () => {
 axios.get(`http://localhost:8080/country_code`).then((res) => {
      const countryData = res.data;
      this.setState({ countryData });
      alert(countryData);
    });
}

componentDidMount() {
  this.updateDropdownData()
}
```

And you can call **this.updateDropdownData()** from anywhere you want. Just like:

```
onSomeUserAction = () => {
 this.updateDropdownData()
}
```

Comment: Thanks Akshay. it still requires page refresh to reflect the same.